# Async Socket High Memory Usage and Possible Leak

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I have a server application rewrite underway and am puzzled by the memory usage of the application. The earlier version was written with `TcpListener` while the new one is plain old `Socket`. This is mostly for performance and stability reasons which are secondary to this question and even this issue.

As mentioned, everything is heavily async'd with `AcceptAsync`, `SendAsync`, and `ReceiveAsync`. On top of that, I use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` for utility tasks such as the initial kick-off for `AcceptAsync` and keeping the next `AcceptAsync` queued, the call after processing to write back to the `Socket`, and the call cleaning up disconnected clients. Further, there are a series of events that I fire with `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`.

The detection for those disconnects as well as the main driver for data availability are handled by a custom class that I call `AvailabilityNotifier` that peaks on a `ReceiveAsync` as well as detecting for `SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred` being zero which fires a `Disconnect` event.

The throughput of the application is good, and there's almost zero (relatively speaking) lock contention thanks to a healthy usage of `System.Collections.Concurrent` objects. However, it clings to memory like a predator clinging to a kill.

I've debugged to verify my internal collections are getting cleared, the client sockets are being shutdown and disposed of, and utilizing a buffer pool instead of creating new buffers for each read. Running a test application that ultimately performs 1,000 connections (100 concurrent) and sends/receives 100,000 messages bloats the server process memory to around 800 MB and it never goes down even after Windows clears any `TIME_WAIT`s that might have happened. I know for sure the diposal code is firing thanks to a ton of `ObjectDisposedException` and null exception `catch` blocks that you can see in the linked github below.

I say all that without quoted code as it's quite long for a post here so here's a github: https://github.com/hoagsie/TcpServer. The `Program.cs` and `ClientProgram.cs` is provided as well if you'd want to run it yourself but the main action is in `NetworkServer.cs` and `AvailabilityNotifier.cs`. The sample server I have running also has a WCF service it talks to but is just the standard WCF project with literally no modifications. I just needed it to match a sample scenario.

I'm also not sure if it matters on some level, but I do build this in x64 mode rather than AnyCPU/x86. This is mostly for resource consumption opportunity on the target server it will be going on, but I haven't noticed a difference in behavior with regard to this issue in either x86 or x64.

**EDIT:**

A coworker pointed out the Snapshot tool in Visual Studio. I had never seen this before and it displayed things differently from what I had been using, which was dotTrace. It pointed to a ton of allocations around the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` object which makes sense, but they kept building and building. I looked at its member list again and discovered it had a `Dispose` method. My issue has gone away. I didn't realize that was an `IDisposable` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker pointed out the Snapshot tool in Visual Studio. I had never seen this before and it displayed things differently from what I had been using, which was dotTrace. It pointed to a ton of allocations around the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` object which makes sense, but they kept building and building. I looked at its member list again and discovered it had a `Dispose` method. My issue has gone away. I didn't realize that was an `IDisposable` object.